# Keyboard randomly stops working after Windows 10 cumulative update

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10

Every few hours it happens and rebooting temporarily fixes it. It still works for Chrome for some reason. How do I fix it for good?

Comment: It's Windows 10, so it's probably a driver issue. Check Device Manager to see if the driver crashes or something. You should also try reinstalling the driver to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is Kaspersky related. I presume you have kaspersky installed. It has still not been fixed after almost 2 months which is quite miserable of them if I say so myself.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer with no facts